Access NodeJS packaged with VisualStudioCode (Electron app)
I'm using MacOS and don't have NodeJS installed but I do have VisualStudioCode. I know that Electron brings its own NodeJS.
How do I access this NodeJS from inside the Terminal.app for example?
Is it even possible? I tried to find node binary in /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/ and didn't find it.
